# Android ViewPager, PageTransformer and GLES20Canvas.nPrepareDirty

Tags: android, multithreading, android-viewpager

I have a problem with transforming relatively simple Fragment in ViewPager using PageTransformer.
I am using support library v4 ViewPager and PageTransformer.

The Fragment consists of few TextViews and an ImageView

The PageTransformer does 3 things to ViewPager Views:

positions [-1,0[

```
view.setTranslationX(calculatedTransition);
view.setScaleX(scale);
view.setScaleY(scale);
```

position (0,1]

```
view.setScaleX(scale);
view.setScaleY(scale);
view.setTranslationX(calculatedTransition);
```

The calculations done in PageTransformer are not complicated and do not cause the problem.

The problem is that every time I come to the ViewPager activity the first drag skips frames at the start. The problem does not continue beyond the first drag. I have performed a ddms trace to see what uses the main thread time. I noticed that during the first drag native method **GLES20Canvas.nPrepareDirty** is called that takes about 200ms of time and causes the lagging.

Not using the PageTransformer does remove the lagging but also removes the important animation.

My question is can I do this in some other thread than main thread or time it so that it would not happen when user is dragging the ViewPager.

Thanks for any help you can give!